# How to find modified files in git, even with reverted commit?

Tags: git

I create a tag in the repository, let's say v1.0.0. Later there are 2 commits: first one with some changes and second one with revert of that changes. I'd like to find all modified files after tagging. 
I tried:

```
git diff --name-only v1.0.0 master
```

but for `git diff` there weren't any changes - files look the same. But I need to know which files were modified, even if that modification was reverted.

Comment: Were changes reverted manually (by editing the code), or by actually reverting the commit?

Comment: Both ways are possible (many people working on this project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest solution is probably `git log --oneline --stat v1.0.0..master`. This will print a list of commits, along with the files they touched:

```
b1be31 Revert "test commit"
 fileA | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
23faef another commit
 fileB | 2 +
 fileC | 3 +
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+)
0821dea test commit
 fileA | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Since every commit is listed, reverted changes will be visible (twice, first the original commit, then the revert commit).

If you want only a list of file names, you'd have to filter this through some kind of script, but for getting a quick list it might be enough. If you start scripting, you might want to look at the plumbing commands to get something that is easier to parse...

Answer (score 3):

I search on the internet for this question, and get nothing. Finally I use this method:

```
git log commit1..commit2 --format="" --name-only | sort | uniq
```

what's important, it works.

Answer (score 0):

When a commit is reverted, the resulting diff would be the same as if the original commit would have never existed, and so the change would not exist anymore.

I think trying to see a reverted diff would give you a false diff of your code which would not make any sense.

If you actually want those changes (they didn't have to be reverted), you can revert the revert commit.

Comment: Incorrect. You are probably mixing up "revert" and "rebase". A reverted commit still exists as a regular commit - there's just later commit reverting it.

Comment: No I didn't mix, I however wrongly said it. What I meant was that if a commit is reverted, in the final diff, the changes of the original commit will not be here (revert's purpose). but the commit will be here indeed. And the final diff would be the same as if the original commit was never be done (and so not reverted either).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But that's not what you wrote in your answer :-).

Comment: I tried to reword it, still not sure it sounds right in the result. I'll try to think about it later after some rest.

Answer (score -1):

From `man git-diff`:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
  This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

So just need the name of this commit before the changes were made, and the commit in which the change were made, then you can run `git diff commit1 commit2`.

Comment: This probably does not help OP. It seems like he/she wants to know *which* files were changed, even if the changes were reverted later.

Comment: That's what the `--name-only` option is for, as in the OP. The output with that options is also exactly what the OP asked for: a list of files.

Comment: Yes, `--name-only` will list the file names. Still, your command does not list files as changed if the changes were reverted, which is what OP wants.

Comment: If the changes were made in one commit and reverted in another, I fail to see how this *won't* list those changes. It just requires you to know in advance which commits were involved, but the OP didn't specify about that.

Comment: Exactly my point: It looks like OP just has a tag and `master`, and wants to see all files changed inbetween, even if the change was reverted. But you're right, the question is not totally clear.

Comment: Well, at least we understand each other now!